elaboration proof for double of conformally flat manifold
I'm reading a paper and there is a proof that the double of a compact locally conformally flat Riemannian manifold with totally geodesic boundary again carries a locally conformally flat structure. The proof is as follows:
Let $ (M^n, g) $ be a locally conformally flat compact manifold with totally geodesic boundary. We denote a boundary neighborhood in $ M $ by $ U_a \cup \partial U_a $, where $ U_a $ is open and $ \partial U_a = \partial M \cap \partial U_a $ is a segment on the boundary. By definition, there is a conformal map $ \varphi_a : U_a \cup \partial U_a \to V_a \cup \partial V_a \subset S^n_+ \cup S^{n-1} $, such that $ V_a \subset S^n_+ $ and $ \partial V_a $ is on the equator. Denote the doubling of $ M $ by $ N = M \cup M^* $. We will define a locally conformally flat smooth structure on $ N $.
Define the corresponding conformal map $ \varphi^*_a $ from $ U^*_a \subset M^* $ to $ V^*_a \subset S^n_- $ through reflection. If $ \varphi_b $ and $ \varphi^*_b $ are another pair of conformal maps such that $ U_a \cap U_b $ (and thus $ U^*_a \cap U^*_b $) is nonempty, then there is a conformal transformation from $ \varphi_a(U_a \cap U_b) $ to $ \varphi_b(U_a \cap U_b) $. Similarly, there is a corresponding conformal transformation $ \varphi^* $ on the counterpart.
By Liouville's theorem, the conformal transformations $ \varphi $ and $ \varphi^* $ can be extended to conformal transformations on $ S^n $, still denoted by $ \varphi $ and $ \varphi^* $. If we can prove that $ \varphi = \varphi^* $, then they define a locally conformally flat smooth structure on $ N $.
Suppose that $ \varphi $ and $ \varphi^* $ are not equal. Then $ \varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi^* $ is not the identity map on $ S^n $. Notice that it is the identity map on $ \varphi_a(\partial(U_a \cap U_b)) $, which is a co-dimension one submanifold contained in the equator. Thus, $ \varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi^* $ must be a reflection with respect to the equator (see, for example, Chap. A in [1]). This gives us a contradiction because $ \varphi^{-1} $ cannot map $ \varphi^*_b(U^*_a \cap U^*_b) \subset S^n_- $ to $ \varphi_a(U_a \cap U_b) \subset S^n_+ $.
I'm getting lost on their definition of the conformal boundary map. What is this set $ U_a \cup \partial U_a $? Is it even open? Don’t we have to find an open set that covers the points where $ M $ is attached to itself, i.e., something like a tubular neighborhood of the boundary, which we then mirror?
Could someone elaborate?

It seems that whoever wrote this text does not know much topology. Incidentally, the notion of totally geodesic boundary they use is also nonstandard. What are you reading?

Boundary value problems for some fully nonlinear elliptic equations by
Szu-yu Sophie Chen (p.9 is the proof). Any sugestion on how to fix this weird set in the definition of phi?

OK, then I am not surprised, it is written by an analyst.

It appears that you are reading a poorly-written paper.

Saying "totally geodesic boundary" is wrong in this context since this is not a conformally-invariant notion. The right terminology is "umbilical" or "umbilic."

One can approach conformal flatness in two (actually, three, but the third approach is more complicated) different, but equivalent, ways: by considering locally conformally flat Riemannian metrics (if dimension $\ge 3$) or using the topological perspective and working with atlases, by mimicking the usual definition of smooth manifolds with boundary. Here is the correct way to define conformal flatness for manifolds with boundary using this approach. Recall that $H^n$ denotes the half-space $\{x\in \mathbb R^n: x_n\ge 0\}$ (not to be confused with the hyperbolic $n$-space!). Define also
$$
\mathring{H}^n:= \{x\in H^n: x_n>0\}. 
$$


Then a conformally-flat $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary is defined as a 2nd countable Hausdorff topological space $M$, equipped with a maximal atlas with values in $H^n$ such that transition maps are restrictions of Moebius transformations of $\mathbb R^n\cup \{\infty\}$. More precisely, a chart in such an atlas is an open subset $U_\alpha\subset M$ and a homeomorphism $\phi_\alpha: U_\alpha\to V_\alpha$, where $V_\alpha$ is an open subset in $H^n$ (of course, with respect to the subspace topology on $H^n$). Transition maps are defined in the usual fashion. Then each $U_\alpha$ can be partitioned in two subsets: $\mathring{U}_\alpha\sqcup \partial U_\alpha$, where
$$
\mathring{U}_\alpha:= \phi_\alpha^{-1}(\mathring{H}^n),$$
$$
\partial U_\alpha:= \phi_\alpha^{-1}(\{x\in H^n: x_n=0\}). 
$$
It is a standard exercise one does in a differential topology class to note that maps
$$
\phi_\beta^{-1}\circ \phi_\alpha
$$
preserve this partition.
Edit. Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a manifolod with conformally flat metric $g$ and umbilic boundary. I will construct an atlas on $M$ as above. Take $x\in M$. If $x$ is not a boundary point of $M$, then there exists a local chart at $x$ with values in $\mathring{H}^n$ such that in this chart the metric $g$ is given by
$$
f(x)\delta_{ij},
$$
where $f(x)$ is a smooth positive function and $\delta_{ij}$ is the  standard Euclidean metric.
Suppose that $x\in \partial M$. Then there exists a local chart $\phi: U\to \mathbb R^n$ at $x$ which $\phi_*(g)=f(x)\delta_{ij}$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $U$ is contractible. By the  umbilic property of $\partial M$, $\phi(\partial U)$ is an open subset of a sphere/hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$. By postcomposing $\phi$ with a Moebius transformation, we may assume that $\phi(\partial U)=\partial H^n$ and $\phi(U)\subset H^n$. This is your atlas. (After you complete it to a maximal one.) I will leave it to you to check that the transition maps of the charts constructed above are restrictions of Moebius transformations (if $n\ge 3$, of course).

Thanks! It makes more sense to me now, but i have one question. I tought in general that the boundary of a locally conformally flat rie. manifold is not nessecarily l.c.f. However a totally umbilical boundary is again lcf. So $\phi_{alpha)}^{-1}$ is a conformal map if and only if the boundary is umbilical? But this statement doesnt make sense to me, since the notion of umbilical stands in no connection to that of a conformal map

@johnka: The sentence "So $\phi_\alpha^{-1}$  is a conformal map if and only if the boundary is umbilical" does not make sense to me either. Maybe you meant to say something else.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that I don't see how the definitions coincide. In the Riemannian case, I understand that umbilical implies that $ \partial M $ is locally conformally flat (LCF) with the induced metric. However, with the atlas definition, as I understand it, we are already saying that each point on the boundary admits a neighborhood together with a conformal map (Möbius map) into some half-space. I suppose I'm getting lost in the different definitions of LCF or in the definition of the induced smooth structure on a submanifold

@johnka: umbilical is much stronger than what you are saying. I will add more details later.

first, thanks for the clarification, however im still a little bit at a loss. i dont see why these transition maps are restrictions of möbius transformations. i dont even see why they are conformal. im sorry, im not so familiar with this

@johnka: Are you familiar with Liouville's theorem about conformal maps?

yes, it says that a conformal transformation between connected open subsets of $S^n$ is the restriction of a möbiustransformation of $S^n$.

@johnka Good. Now, prove the following: Let $U_1, U_2$ be open conected subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ with conformal metrics $g_1, g_2$, i.e. $g_1, g_2$ is a scalar function times of the Euclidean metric. Then every isometry $\phi: (U_1, g_1)\to (U_2, g_2)$ preserves Euclidean angles between vectors. Conclude (assuming $n\ge 3$) that $\phi$ is the restriction of a Moebius transformation.
